# DB2 Create DB command results in SQL1005N database directory or system database directory already exists

Tags: database, windows, db2

I have a fresh install of Windows 10 and DB2 v10.5 FP 7.

I am trying to create a simple DB and keep gettings a SQL1005N error.  This is a new install and so there are no existing DBs:

```
db2 => list node directory

Node Directory

Number of entries in the directory = 1

Node 1 entry:

Node name                      = DEVWIN10
Comment                        =
Directory entry type           = LOCAL
Protocol                       = TCPIP
Hostname                       = 192.168.1.14
Service name                   = 50000

db2 => list db directory
SQL1057W  The system database directory is empty.  SQLSTATE=01606

db2 => attach to devwin10 user db2admin using <PASSWORD>
Instance Attachment Information

Instance server        = DB2/NT64 10.5.7
Authorization ID       = DB2ADMIN
Local instance alias   = DEVWIN10

db2 => CREATE DATABASE DEMO
SQL1005N  The database alias "DEMO" already exists in either the local database directory or system database directory.

db2 => CREATE DATABASE DEMODB
SQL1005N  The database alias "DEMODB" already exists in either the local database directory or system database directory.

db2 => CREATE DATABASE ANTHONY
SQL1005N  The database alias "ANTHONY" already exists in either the local database directory or system database directory.

db2 => CREATE DATABASE BLAH
SQL1005N  The database alias "BLAH" already exists in either the local database directory or system database directory.
```

As you can see it doesn't matter what DB name I choose, I always get the same error.  The DB is created:

```
db2 => list db directory

System Database Directory

Number of entries in the directory = 4

Database 1 entry:

Database alias                       = ANTHONY
Database name                        = ANTHONY
Local database directory             = C:
Database release level               = 10.00
Comment                              =
Directory entry type                 = Indirect
Catalog database partition number    = 0
Alternate server hostname            =
Alternate server port number         =

Database 2 entry:
...
Database 3 entry:
...
Database 4 entry:
...
```

But I can't connect to it:

```
db2 => connect to BLAH user db2admin using <PASSWORD>
SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot be connected to in the mode requested.  SQLSTATE=57019

db2 => connect to ANTHONY user db2admin using <PASSWORD>
SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot be connected to in the mode requested.  SQLSTATE=57019

db2 => connect to DEMO user db2admin using <PASSWORD>
SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot be connected to in the mode requested.  SQLSTATE=57019

db2 => connect to DEMODB user db2admin using <PASSWORD>
SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot be connected to in the mode requested.  SQLSTATE=57019
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently I need to run the command:

```
CREATE DATABASE DEMODB AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES ON 'C:\' DBPATH ON 'C:\'
```

This fully creates the DB and allows me to connect to it and use it.

```
db2 => CONNECT TO DEMODB USER DB2ADMIN USING <PASSWORD>

Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2/NT64 10.5.7
SQL authorization ID   = DB2ADMIN
Local database alias   = DEMODB
```

Of course it needs to be started:

```
ACTIVATE DATABASE DEMODB
```

Answer (score 0):

db2 catalog the database using "`db2 catalog db SAMPLE on <path>`"

```
db2 terminate
db2 drop database SAMPLE
```

Run the restore command again.